# Save value between function calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I wrote a simple decorator to cache values in case a function call would return `''`.  Is there a better way to store the value than the dictionary I'm currently using? Would using `hasattr` be more pythonic and, if so, how to implement? Would something else be better?

```
def cache(func):
# Caching decorator
# if result is '', return saved value
# else save and return result

    saved = {1:''}
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result:
            saved[1] = result
            return result
        return saved[1]
    return newfunc
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it more pythonic, but just pass a dict of attributes to and from your function?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't understand your comment. Please rephrase.

Comment: `{'var1' : val1, 'var2 : val2 }` have your function accept this, use this, and then return this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the result as an attribute of the original function seems a bit more pythonic:

```
def cache(func):
    func._result = ''
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result:
            func._result = result            
        return func._result
    return newfunc
```

Comment: It does seem move pythonic